# Is there a way to stop queued JUnit tests and still keep the JavaFX Gui running?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, junit, webdriver

I'm writing a program that sets up a GUI to start JUnit test scripts that utilize Selenium WebDriver in Java. The GUI sets up a queue of JUnit tests in the background (or so i believe). On the GUI, I want to utilize a "stop test" button that will stop all future JUnit tests that are still in the Queue from executing, but i want to do it in a timely manner. I currently have code that will stop all tests, but if 190 tests are in the queue, it takes upwards of 1-2 seconds to stop a singular test in the queue from executing which is not timely nor consumer friendly when you consider that many tests:

```
Field field = JUnitCore.class.getDeclaredField("fNotifier");
field.setAccessible(true);
RunNotifier runNotifier = (RunNotifier) field.get(runner);
runNotifier.pleaseStop();
```

is there a way to either clear the queue of the JUnit test or a specific thread to close that will stop the execution of scripts without killing the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting this recently, i found out that run notifier in my question works fast enough, i just had too many sub processes that i recently optimized during the stop test action. Now run notifier allows for the queued tests to realize they can't be ran almost instantaneously.

Though this technically doesn't answer the question of how to stop queued JUnit Tests from executing without at least attempting to start them, though.

Answer (score 3):

How are you defining your threads in your xml file? Found some stuff using the parallel variable to kill all specific threads immediately. Maybe if you name your threads with something common and increment a counter to put a "_1" ... "_2" and so on at the end of the common name, you could loop through quickly and kill the thread directly? You mentioned a queue of tests that you weren't positive on how it worked, maybe take the queue into your own hands manually and kill them all.

Comment: I had tried this at an earlier date, and couldn't successfully locate the threads in the code that were executing the JUnit tests unless i killed a thread that was necessary for the GUI to run.

Comment: What if you restared the GUI and disposed of the old one. MainGuiClass.this.dispose();
new MainGuiClass();
Or something to that effect

Comment: I'll take a look into this, but preferably, i'd like to find a way to keep the GUI  up and running until the user decides they want to stop the tests. The GUI takes a good 10 seconds to load, so that wouldn't be very user friendly.